# Return the "diff" between two sequential results

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

Question : Can I instead of showing the `Measured` value show the change in the value? I have perl code, and I want the SQL to return what the perl code returns instead of having to use the code to make it into the desired data.

Background: I have the following SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Stats` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `MeasuredTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `Measured` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `What` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

And SQL data:

```
+-------+---------------------+----------+------+
| ID    | MeasuredTime        | Measured | What |
+-------+---------------------+----------+------+
| 45403 | 2013-12-16 14:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 45398 | 2013-12-16 13:31:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 45393 | 2013-12-16 13:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 45388 | 2013-12-16 12:31:02 |     4379 |    5 |
| 45383 | 2013-12-16 12:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 45378 | 2013-12-16 11:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45373 | 2013-12-16 11:01:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45368 | 2013-12-16 10:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45363 | 2013-12-16 10:01:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45358 | 2013-12-16 09:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45353 | 2013-12-16 09:01:02 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45348 | 2013-12-16 08:31:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45343 | 2013-12-16 08:01:02 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45338 | 2013-12-16 07:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45333 | 2013-12-16 07:01:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45328 | 2013-12-16 06:31:02 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45323 | 2013-12-16 06:01:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45318 | 2013-12-16 05:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45313 | 2013-12-16 05:01:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45308 | 2013-12-16 04:31:02 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45303 | 2013-12-16 04:01:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45298 | 2013-12-16 03:31:02 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45293 | 2013-12-16 03:01:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45288 | 2013-12-16 02:31:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45283 | 2013-12-16 02:01:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45278 | 2013-12-16 01:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45273 | 2013-12-16 01:01:02 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45268 | 2013-12-16 00:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45263 | 2013-12-16 00:01:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45258 | 2013-12-15 23:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45253 | 2013-12-15 23:01:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45248 | 2013-12-15 22:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45243 | 2013-12-15 22:01:02 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45238 | 2013-12-15 21:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45233 | 2013-12-15 21:01:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45228 | 2013-12-15 20:31:02 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45223 | 2013-12-15 20:01:02 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45218 | 2013-12-15 19:31:02 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45213 | 2013-12-15 19:01:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45208 | 2013-12-15 18:31:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45203 | 2013-12-15 18:01:02 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45198 | 2013-12-15 17:31:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 45193 | 2013-12-15 17:01:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45188 | 2013-12-15 16:31:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45183 | 2013-12-15 16:01:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45178 | 2013-12-15 15:31:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45173 | 2013-12-15 15:01:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45168 | 2013-12-15 14:31:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45163 | 2013-12-15 14:01:02 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45158 | 2013-12-15 13:31:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45153 | 2013-12-15 13:01:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45148 | 2013-12-15 12:31:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45143 | 2013-12-15 12:01:02 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45138 | 2013-12-15 11:31:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45133 | 2013-12-15 11:01:01 |     4375 |    5 |
| 45128 | 2013-12-15 10:31:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45123 | 2013-12-15 10:01:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45118 | 2013-12-15 09:31:01 |     4376 |    5 |
| 45113 | 2013-12-15 09:01:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 45108 | 2013-12-15 08:31:01 |     4381 |    5 |
| 45103 | 2013-12-15 08:01:01 |     4381 |    5 |
| 45098 | 2013-12-15 07:31:01 |     4381 |    5 |
| 45093 | 2013-12-15 07:01:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 45088 | 2013-12-15 06:31:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 45083 | 2013-12-15 06:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 45078 | 2013-12-15 05:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 45073 | 2013-12-15 05:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 45068 | 2013-12-15 04:31:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 45063 | 2013-12-15 04:01:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 45058 | 2013-12-15 03:31:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 45053 | 2013-12-15 03:01:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 45048 | 2013-12-15 02:31:02 |     4383 |    5 |
| 45043 | 2013-12-15 02:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 45038 | 2013-12-15 01:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 45033 | 2013-12-15 01:01:01 |     4385 |    5 |
| 45028 | 2013-12-15 00:31:01 |     4385 |    5 |
| 45023 | 2013-12-15 00:01:01 |     4385 |    5 |
| 45018 | 2013-12-14 23:31:01 |     4385 |    5 |
| 45013 | 2013-12-14 23:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 45008 | 2013-12-14 22:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 45003 | 2013-12-14 22:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44998 | 2013-12-14 21:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44993 | 2013-12-14 21:01:02 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44988 | 2013-12-14 20:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44983 | 2013-12-14 20:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44978 | 2013-12-14 19:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44973 | 2013-12-14 19:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44968 | 2013-12-14 18:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44963 | 2013-12-14 18:01:02 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44958 | 2013-12-14 17:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44953 | 2013-12-14 17:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44948 | 2013-12-14 16:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44943 | 2013-12-14 16:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44938 | 2013-12-14 15:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44933 | 2013-12-14 15:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44928 | 2013-12-14 14:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44923 | 2013-12-14 14:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44918 | 2013-12-14 13:31:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44913 | 2013-12-14 13:01:01 |     4384 |    5 |
| 44908 | 2013-12-14 12:31:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 44903 | 2013-12-14 12:01:01 |     4383 |    5 |
| 44898 | 2013-12-14 11:31:02 |     4383 |    5 |
| 44893 | 2013-12-14 11:01:02 |     4381 |    5 |
| 44888 | 2013-12-14 10:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44883 | 2013-12-14 10:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44878 | 2013-12-14 09:31:02 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44873 | 2013-12-14 09:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44868 | 2013-12-14 08:31:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44863 | 2013-12-14 08:01:02 |     4378 |    5 |
| 44858 | 2013-12-14 07:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 44853 | 2013-12-14 07:01:11 |     4378 |    5 |
| 44848 | 2013-12-14 06:31:01 |     4378 |    5 |
| 44843 | 2013-12-14 06:01:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44838 | 2013-12-14 05:31:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44833 | 2013-12-14 05:01:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44828 | 2013-12-14 04:31:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44823 | 2013-12-14 04:01:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44818 | 2013-12-14 03:31:02 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44813 | 2013-12-14 03:01:02 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44808 | 2013-12-14 02:31:01 |     4377 |    5 |
| 44803 | 2013-12-14 02:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44798 | 2013-12-14 01:31:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44793 | 2013-12-14 01:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44788 | 2013-12-14 00:31:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44783 | 2013-12-14 00:01:01 |     4379 |    5 |
| 44778 | 2013-12-13 23:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44773 | 2013-12-13 23:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44768 | 2013-12-13 22:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44763 | 2013-12-13 22:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44758 | 2013-12-13 21:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44753 | 2013-12-13 21:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44748 | 2013-12-13 20:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44743 | 2013-12-13 20:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44738 | 2013-12-13 19:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44733 | 2013-12-13 19:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44728 | 2013-12-13 18:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44723 | 2013-12-13 18:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44718 | 2013-12-13 17:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44713 | 2013-12-13 17:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44708 | 2013-12-13 16:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44703 | 2013-12-13 16:01:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44698 | 2013-12-13 15:31:01 |     4380 |    5 |
| 44693 | 2013-12-13 15:01:02 |     4380 |    5 |
```

The table has an `ID` (which is an auto increment), a `MeasuredTime` which is the time value when the measurement was done, `Measured` which is the value being measured and `What` which is an int value for the type of measurement taken.

I would like to compare two time sequential values and just return the difference, rather than the value. I am currently doing it in `perl` but I would like to do it in SQL to ease the code load, and I believe it will be also more efficient.

Here is the code I use, I skipped the SQL which just does:

```
SELECT ID, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MeasuredTime), Measured, What
FROM Stats
WHERE What  = 5 AND 
MeasuredTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Code:

```
my @array; // Contains %Hash
my @new_array;
for(my $pos = 0; $pos < scalar @array - 1; $pos++) {
 my %CurrentItem = %{$array[$pos]};
 my %NextItem = %{$array[$pos+1]};

 my %NewItem;
 $NewItem{Measured} = ($CurrentItem{Measured} - $NextItem{Measured});
 $NewItem{MeasuredTime} = ($CurrentItem{MeasuredTime} + $NextItem{MeasuredTime}) / 2; # So we average the time somewhere in the middle
 $NewItem{What} = 5;
 $NewItem{ID} = $pos; # The id value is less important here

 push @new_array, \%NewItem;
}

# At this point @new_array has the diff between the two rows, and has 1 less item than 
#  before
```

Comment: What happens when you run the "code". What do you expect to happen? What is the actual question you are asking? Looks like you have a good question, just not being specific...

Comment: I actually started with the question, I have perl code that works, that is not the problem, I want the perl code to become SQL code that returns the diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html):

```sql
SELECT   ID, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MeasuredTime), Measured, What,
         Measured - @prev AS diff, @prev := Measured
FROM     Stats, (SELECT @prev := NULL) AS init
WHERE    What = 5
     AND MeasuredTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8946f/4/0).

Comment: Thanks :) never thought of doing this

Comment: Funny good solution, only id could be a prob -> order my mesuredTime?

Comment: @halfbit: Maybe. I've no idea. The original code in the question was sorted by `ID`, so I assumed the OP knew what they were doing there.  Obviously if a different ordering is required, it should be applied.

Comment: ID is ordered and MeasuredTime is also ordered, and they "match" now ID is not sequential as several things are measured every "several minutes"

Comment: @eggyal: not matter, just a comment, I am still kneeing in front of this solution

Comment: @nrathaus: there is a 'never ever' depend on (order of) ID: imagine, somone deletes 10.000 rows by accident, and inserts them again ...  ID ok, order on ID _done_  but time ok

Comment: I am not depending on the ID, its just goes up as the time goes up, there is no "collision". And if someone deletes the data, but inserts it in the wrong order, well, that data will be corrupt, but seriously, that is plain stupid recovery procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT A.* ,(A.Measured - B.Measured) AS difference
FROM `stats` A CROSS JOIN `stats` B
WHERE B.ID IN (SELECT MIN(C.ID) FROM `stats` C WHERE C.ID > A.ID)
ORDER BY A.ID ASC
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8da61/1)